# Can "Request method 'PUT' not supported" be due to a bad JSON input?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, postman

I am trying to test the following web service from PostMan.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/share")
public class ShareController {

    @ApiOperation(value = "Creates a data Request")
    @PostMapping(value = "/request", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    @AuditAccess(message = "Accessing /share/request")
    public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> submitShareRequest(HttpServletRequest request,
              @RequestBody ShareRequest shareRequest) throws ValidationException
```

I keep seeing the following message in my JBoss log:

> HttpServletRequest: SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[
> org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@1d0e84dc].
> The exception message: Request method 'PUT' not supported

Could this be due to JSON that doesn't correspond to the `@RequestBody ShareRequest shareRequest` argument?  I feel sure that I have the correct URL set up in my test.  The protocol, host, and port variables are set to what I expect.  (The "/api" part is set in a `Configuration` object.)  I *think* the JSON I have is correct, but there are a lot more opportunities to go wrong there.

[image]

I'm open to any good suggestions on how to debug this also.

Comment: `@PostMapping` You have a POST, not a PUT.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `@PostMapping` in your controller method. Since you want it to handle PUT requests you need to change it to `@PutMapping`.

Comment: OMG.  I stared at that for so long without noticing.  D'oh.  Thanks!